# SSMS 2008: Debugging made easy?

Tags: sql, debugging, dynamic

I want to alter the procedure sys.sp_executesql in the master database (in the enhanced procedures folder or whatever that's called in English) because I want the procedure to print everything I pass to it.

My code is getting a bit ugly and bloated with all the...

```
if @d=1 print @sqlstatement (@d für debug)
```

...statements in front of my dynamic SQL execute statements. I have to do this because SSMS will not tell be the line number of an error of dynamic SQL. I print all the dynamic SQL before execution  so that I know exactly what dynamic sql came before the error.

How I get rid of all the print statements to clean my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply find them all and erase, what else?

Or find the code, which produces this dynamic sql and modify it for non-producing such a code.